# Push a Message via a Database Trigger?

Tags: mysql, curl

I am trying to use Database trigger and procedure to send sms I have create the table and I can insert data by:

```
use sms;  
INSERT INTO sms_out (id, sender,receiver,msg) 
     VALUES ('','MyName','25578200000',"test");
```

I have created trigger as;

```
use sms;  
CREATE TRIGGER push_message_trigger AFTER INSERT ON sms_out  
FOR EACH ROW  
CALL push_message(NEW.sender, NEW.receiver, NEW.msg);
```

and I have created procedure as;

```
use sms;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE push_message
    (p1 TEXT,
     p2 DOUBLE,
     p3 TEXT)
BEGIN

     DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
     DECLARE result CHAR(255);
     SET cmd = CONCAT('curl "http://www.sms.co.tz/api.php?do=sms&username=Myusername&password=MyPassword&senderid=MyName&dest=25571500000&msg=test"');
      SET result = sys_eval(cmd);

END$$;
```

The above does not work but if I replace

```
SET cmd = CONCAT('curl "http://www.sms.co.tz/api.php?do=sms&username=Myusername&password=MyPassword&senderid=MyName&dest=25571500000&msg=test"');
```

With

```
SET cmd = CONCAT('touch /var/lib/mysql/Advo');
```

It works!!

Whats wrong with curl??

Comment: "The above does not work" - thanks for giving us sufficient info to help you. That explanation is like, super sufficient for anyone to figure out HOW it doesn't work and especially why. Good thing that you tried using curl from terminal to determine whether you even have it working.

Comment: Thank you

On the CentOS terminal I can successfully run this command and send sms

**curl "http://www.sms.co.tz/api.php?do=sms&username=Myusername&password=MyPassword&senderid=MyName&dest=25571500000&msg=test"**

But when I run through MySQL procedure as shown above it does not send sms and log the following error message

**curl: (7) Failed to connect to 41.79.68.155: Permission denied
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'ÿÿÿÿÿ°úó'**

Comment: I found that CentOS was blocking me from sending the sms after Googling I found the solution at http://www.akashif.co.uk/php/curl-error-7-failed-to-connect-to-permission-denied/comment-page-1  
1
nano /etc/selinux/config
locate following line

1
SELINUX=enforcing
Change this to

1
SELINUX=disabled
reboot is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem it's not the curl literal is how are you using mysql CONCAT funcion.

- To concat strings you should do something like (if you don't use commas you aren't concatening strings):

  CONCAT(str1, str2, ....);
- Seems that the problem are the quotes, try to escape the double quotes like this \"

*** Show the error if you want people to know what's really happening